# What should I use to access NFS from console without mounting it?

Tags: linux, console, nfs

```
Network file access  |   Console program |   mounting option
------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP                 |    wget / curl    |   httpfs
FTP                  |    ftp / wget     |   curlftpfs
SMB                  |    smbclient      |   in-kernel or smbnetfs
WebDAV               |    cadaver        |   davfs2, fusedav
SSH                  |    ssh / scp      |   sshfs
NFS                  |       ?           |   in-kernel
```

How do I just download the file or create a directory on NFS without setting it up permanently?

I see there is `libnfs` (it also has [some utils](https://github.com/sahlberg/libnfs/tree/master/utils)), but is there a fully fledged tool based on it?

Comment: Is this question better here, on [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: While it doesn't use the `nfs` protocol, `scp` would let you copy files to the system that is the source of the share.

Comment: @Paul, It would be not useful for testing if NFS is properly configured, for example.

Comment: No, but as NFS is a mounted filesystem, then to adequately test it, it should be mounted.

Comment: @Paul, Are they really that different so there can be `smbclient` for SMB, but not `nfsclient` for NFS?

Comment: They are different in that nfs was designed to be a networked file system for *nix and SMB is a Windows file transfer protocol.   You said you want to test it is configured correct, and as it will only be used mounted, then mounting it is how you need to test it is configured correctly.  Copying a file would not test that mounting works even if there was a way to do it.

Comment: It's a good question, showing that NFS is the only protocol that cannot be used **without sudo mount**. See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/825246/mount-an-nfs-share-as-non-root-user-in-cli/825248

Comment: @NoamManos, I expect it to be accessible without bumping privileges using UML (user-mode Linux).